# Create a html5 that can be use as web and phone/tablet app

Tags: html, mobile

I want to create a html5 web site that when you are on a computer, you will use it as a normal web page, but when you are on a phone/tablet you will need to download the app. Is there a way to code only 1 time the app but it can be deployed as a phone/tablet app also ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: As a possible quick end to wondering I'd suggest looking into something like Apache's Cordova. However, that won't be the answer to all the questions that will come from this. Also take @j08691 advice on the question format.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the HTML5 code considering screen sizes then you can use a tool like Apache Cordova or directly create a new project on the targeted environment (Windows Phone, Android, iOS or others) then just use the webview (or webbrowser) controls to open the HTML file.

the following are links could help you:
- Cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/

- Windows Phone: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431797(v=vs.105).aspx
- Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
- iOS: http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/